# firebase query by property name ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
  {users:
    simpleLogin:1
       user:{
         name:'something',
         email:'something'
       }
    simpleLogin:2
       user:{
         name: 'somethingelse',
         email: 'somethingelse'
       },
       school:{
         schoolname: 'something',
         schoolemail: 'something'
       }
   }
```

so as you can see, some have the 'school' property while others don't. I just want to return an array of only ones with the 'school' property in it. I'm using ionic framework

Comment: And, in your code that you tried, what's the error you get?

Comment: Actually, I don't get an error, the display renders with blank spots in the list because some items don't have that school property. You would think there was an error, right? But I'm not seeing one in the console. I'm going to give the answer below a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase queries can only test for values, not for the existence of keys. So unfortunately there is no way to create the query you want without modifying the data.

But if you do modify the data, e.g. like this:

```
  {users:
    simpleLogin:1
       user:{
         name:'something',
         email:'something'
       },
       hasSchool: false
    simpleLogin:2
       user:{
         name: 'somethingelse',
         email: 'somethingelse'
       },
       hasSchool: true,
       school:{
         schoolname: 'something',
         schoolemail: 'something'
       }
   }
```

You can create a query like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/users');
var query = ref.orderByChild('hasSchool').equalTo(true);
```

You can then bind the users matching the query to your Angular view with:

```
$scope.usersWithSchool = new $firebaseArray(query);
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. I appreciate the help.